# Nginx equivalent of printf() to debug complicated configurations

Tags: nginx

Is there some option in Nginx that I could use to debug which way a request goes through certain "location" blocks? I don't want to turn on full debug log for the whole server just have some "printf()" inside a nested location block.

It's only used to figure out how to configure Nginx as I'm new to it so no need for performance in production use.

I already tried setting different headers but apparently adding headers only works if no headers have been added in a more specific location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just learned about the "echo" module (https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/echo/) which is almost exactly what I wanted.